# How correct add and show UIView on tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, addsubview

I try show checkmark(GitHub WVCheckMark) when i tap on button. Here is code, and it work only when i tap on button second time.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    mark = [[WVCheckMark alloc] init];//WithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)];
    mark.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    //[mark setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    //[self.view addSubview:mark];
}

- (IBAction) btnShow{

    [mark setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    [self.view addSubview:mark];
    [mark setNeedsDisplay];
    [mark updateConstraints];
    [mark setNeedsLayout];

    [mark start];
}
```

It's work how i want (tap and show) if use addSubview in viewDidLoad.

Calling this methods don't help.

```
[mark setNeedsDisplay];
[mark updateConstraints];
[mark setNeedsLayout];
```

Is it possible add subview and show it in one place of code?

Full code

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TestCheckmark-Swift.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

WVCheckMark *mark;

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    mark = [[WVCheckMark alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)];
    mark.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [mark setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    //[self.view addSubview:mark];
}

- (IBAction) btnShow{

    //[mark setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    //[self.view addSubview:mark];
    [mark setNeedsDisplay];
    [mark updateConstraints];
    [mark setNeedsLayout];

    [mark start];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Comment: Debug in `btnShow`. Is it called? (remove the three setNeed...updateCo...)

Comment: methods `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` called according to viewCont life cycle, just add the button inside `viewDidAppear` before you apply any code on it.

Comment: @shallowThought yes, btnShow called when i tap it's first time

Comment: @vaibhav, yes this question is more to understand what's going in viewDidAppear, and can this do in btnShow

Comment: I think how you declared mark is incorrect, can you show us that code?

Comment: @yawnobleix i added full code to question. code is work - checkmark show and animated-, if addSubView in viewDidLoad but i want add subview in btnShow. Or understand why add view in btnShow is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  the OP code doesn't need to call `setNeedsDisplay`, `setNeedsLayout`, `updateConstraints` on the added view, but it does need to call `addSubview:` on the parent view, as in `[self.view addSubview:mark];`

But to go a little deeper, it looks like WVCheckMark on GitHub is a subclass of UIView.  That's a good, important thing because it means we can probably count on some desirable stuff inherited from UIView.

For example, the `.alpha` property, which is a good way to alter visibility without messing around with the view hierarchy (adding and removing child views).  Another nice thing about `.alpha` is that -- unlike `.hidden` -- alpha can be animated.

So let's setup the view hierarchy and framing in one place.  The key idea -- and the idea probably most confounding the OP code -- is to call `addSubview:`.  Doing the setup lazily is a good way to insure we do it exactly once, at the point we need to.

```
- (WVCheckMark *)mark {
    WVCheckMark *mark = [self.view viewWithTag:64];  // 64 must be non-zero and unique amongst self.view subviews
    if (!mark) {
        mark = [[WVCheckMark alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
        mark.tag = 64;  // so we can find it later
        mark.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        // start out invisible
        mark.alpha = 0.0;
        // important, addSubview, which is probably the main problem in the OP
        [self.view addSubview:mark];
    }
    return mark;
}
```

Now, whenever you need to show/hide that view, just do this:

```
self.mark.alpha = 1.0;  // show
self.mark.alpha = 0.0;  // hide
```

Since that property is animatable, you can get a little fancy fade like this:

```
- (void)setMarkHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSTimeInterval duration = (animated)? 0.3 : 0.0;
    CGFloat alpha = (hidden)? 0.0 : 1.0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        self.mark.alpha = alpha;
    }];
}
```

You can throw away all of your other check mark related code, and just do this when the button is pressed to trigger the appearance...

```
- (IBAction)pressed:(id)sender {
    [setMarkHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```